Reformatting a tsibble in R
So i have train_set_tsibble, where
> str(train_set_tsibble)
    tbl_ts [31 × 2] (S3: tbl_ts/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
      $ date  : Date[1:31], format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-02" "2015-01-03" ...
       $ Delays: num [1:31] 25 52 57 76 41 46 37 42 32 16 ...
       - attr(*, "key")= tibble [26 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
              ..$ Delays: num [1:26] 12 13 16 18 21 23 24 25 26 28 ...
              ..$ .rows : list<int> [1:26] 
              .. ..$ : int 24
              .. ..$ : int 19
              .. ..$ : int [1:3] 10 14 25
              .. ..$ : int 23
              .. ..$ : int 20
              .. ..$ : int 27
              .. ..$ : int 15
              .. ..$ : int 1
              .. ..$ : int 13
              .. ..$ : int 22
              .. ..$ : int 17
              .. ..$ : int 28
              .. ..$ : int 9
              .. ..$ : int 18
              .. ..$ : int 7
              .. ..$ : int 12
              .. ..$ : int [1:3] 5 21 26
              .. ..$ : int 8
              .. ..$ : int 16
              .. ..$ : int 29
              .. ..$ : int 6
              .. ..$ : int 2
              .. ..$ : int [1:2] 3 31
              .. ..$ : int 11
              .. ..$ : int 4
              .. ..$ : int 30
              .. ..@ ptype: int(0) 
        ..- attr(*, ".drop")= logi TRUE
       - attr(*, "index")= chr "date"
        ..- attr(*, "ordered")= logi TRUE
       - attr(*, "index2")= chr "date"
       - attr(*, "interval")= interval [1:1] 1D
        ..@ .regular: logi TRUE
  - attr(*, ".regular")= logi TRUE

This causes errors when I try to apply it in model(), I assume because the key tibble is formatted really incorrectly.
I think if I had it formatted like this it would be good:
 > str(train_set_tsibble)
      tbl_ts [31 × 2] (S3: tbl_ts/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
       $ date  : Date[1:31], format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-02" "2015-01-03" ...
       $ Delays: num [1:31] 25 52 57 76 41 46 37 42 32 16 ...
       - attr(*, "key")= tibble [1 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
        ..$ .rows : list<int> [1:31] 
              .. ..$ : int 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 20 ...
              .. ..@ ptype: int(0) 
        ..- attr(*, ".drop")= logi TRUE
        - attr(*, "index")= chr "date"
        ..- attr(*, "ordered")= logi TRUE
             - attr(*, "index2")= chr "date"
             - attr(*, "interval")= interval [1:1] 1D
        ..@ .regular: logi TRUE
             - attr(*, ".regular")= logi TRUE

I'm not really sure what to do, everytime I try to manually change the tibble key it only adds more values.

Thanks for sharing the details of the data, but often posting a simple dput(head(train_set_tsibble)) can be much more informative because potential answers can use it when testing for errors.
